# How do I specify a conditional parameter in HTML::Template::Pro?

Tags: perl

I'm writing it this way but it's causing my program to abort:

```
HTML::Template::Pro->new(filename=>$file, filter => $filter ? $filter : undef);
```

What's wrong in the above code?

Basically I want the conditional filter to do `encode_entities()` on each `TMPL_VAR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`undef` is not a valid value for `filter`.  Instead, omit the filter parameter altogether, like this:

```
HTML::Template::Pro->new(filename=>$file, $filter ? (filter => $filter) : ());
```

Comment: @asker : That's another question